# Convert WAV File into 2 separate PCM files using NAudio

Tags: c#, stream, wav, naudio, pcm

I have a task for work, I need to convert a local .wav file into 2 separate PCM files.

I have managed to read the file into a WavStream or into a Byte[] but have no knowledge on how to convert each channel to a separate file, without losing the headers.

Sample Code will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Nokky.

P.S

This is the code I used.

```
public void WavToPcmConvert(string filePath)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);

    using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(filePath))
    {
        using (var converter = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader))
        {
              WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(, converter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a PCM file, samples are interleaved left, right. Assuming you have 16 bit samples, this means you get two bytes left channel, two bytes right, and so on.

So create two `WaveFileWriter`s, then read a second's worth of audio from converter, loop through the bytes you've read, and write alternating pairs into each `WaveFileWriter`. Keep going until you get to the end of your input stream (`converter.Read` returns 0).